# unable to use macros in dbt models

Tags: transformation, dbt

--macro
{% macro get_payment_methods3(p_org_id1) %}

{% set query %}
SELECT * FROM transaction_test
{% endset %}

{% do run_query(query) %}

{% endmacro %}

this is my macro and i am not able to use it in model.

--model
SELECT * ,
{{get_payment_methods3('p_org_id1') }}
FROM transaction_test

04:43:34
04:43:34  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
04:43:34
04:43:34  Database Error in model m3 (models\m3.sql)
04:43:34    001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
04:43:34    syntax error line 12 at position 0 unexpected 'FROM'.
04:43:34    compiled Code at target\run\d1\models\m3.sql
04:43:34
04:43:34  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1

i am new to this macro.. help much needed

macro implementation

Comment: You have some compiled code in `target\run\d1\models\m3.sql`. I'd start opening that file and checking the result of your compiled SQL